# Angular template driven form - how to bind parent to child

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I made a component named citizenNumber with **template driven** form.

To bind ngModels I used **ControlContainer** provider.

```
@Component({
selector: 'jhi-citizen-number',
styles: [],
viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }],
providers: [
    {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CitizenNumberComponent),
    multi: true
    }
],
template: `
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label class = "form-control-label label-color" 
            for = "citizenNumber">Citizen Number
            </label>
            <input type = "text" 
                class = "form-control input-css" 
                name = "citizenNumber" 
                id = "citizenNumber"
                #citizenNumber = "ngModel"
                [(ngModel)] = "value">
    `
})
```

I give component name #citizenNumber inside.

**I am trying to give component name in PARENT form.** (To use the component multiple time with different names in parent)

```
<form #parentForm="ngForm" novalidate>
    <jhi-citizen-number [(ngModel)]="citizenNumber" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    </jhi-citizen-number>
</form>
```

Look the component in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-citizen-number?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Can you help me with my problem?**

Comment: you can use a `[name]` input property and use it in your component's code. You already have 2 input properties, so I think you know how to do it. Just declare a string property with name "name" and use it's value in the template.

Comment: And, do NOT use `id="..."` in your template. You really don't need id attributes in Angular. It would cause unexpected errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I declared a [name] property and its work.